# How to colorize text of a displayed dataframe when using ipywidgets for an interactive output?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am working on this problem to consume and compare the differences between two plans. Long story short, if we take route A, or route B we will incur different outcomes. I've created a few interactive buttons using ipywidgets that control a seaborn linegraph as expected. Where I'm having trouble, is I want to display a short dataframe and colorize based on a set of criteria.

I can colorize outside of my interactive output by using display( df.style.applymap(color_defining_function) ). However, when I try to do this with a function that I've defined that will take an interactive input and filter the table to show relevant information and then draw the table it will no longer work. I've tried to put some relevant sample code here.

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
import pandas as pd

years = range(2020, 2025, 1)
df = pd.DataFrame(years, columns=['Years'])

# Make the interactions and get the dropdown values
slider = widgets.IntSlider( min= min(years), max= max(years) )

# Make the ui and define the function to create graphs. 
ui = widgets.HBox([slider])

# Define function that will return blue text for the year 2021
def color_blue_2021(val):
    color = 'blue' if val == '2021' else 'black'
    return 'color: %s' % color

# Draw table function that filters based on slider value and displays the table
def draw_table(year):
    displayed_df = df.loc[ df['Years'] <= year]
    return display( displayed_df.style.applymap(color_blue_2021), clear = True )

table_out = widgets.interactive(draw_table, year = slider)
display(ui, table_out)
```

Any ideas on why this isn't highlighting the value 2021 as blue?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the years in my dataframe were stored as dtype integer, while I was looking for it being equal to a string for 2021. It seems to work as desired now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).